# If I use a composite hashing strategy for strings can I virtually eliminate collisions?

Tags: hash

Ok so here's the use case.  I have lots of somewhat lengthy (200-500 character) strings that I'd like to have a smaller deterministic hash for.  Since I can store the full 160-bit SHA1 value in a mere 20 bytes, this yields an order of magnitude space improvement per string.

But of course one has to worry about collisions with hashing on strings even with a crypto hash with decent avalanche effects.  I know the chances are infintesimely small, but I'd like to be more conservative.  If I do something like this:

**hash(input) =  CONCAT(HF1(input),HF2(input))**

where `HF1` is some suitable robust hashing f() and `HF2` is another distinct but robust hashing f().  Does this effectively make the chance of a collision near impossible (At the cost of 40 bytes now instead of 20)?
NOTE: I am not concerned with the security/crypto implications of SHA-1 for my use case.

CLARIFICATION:  original question was posed about a hashing the concatenated hash value, not concatenating hashes which DOES NOT change the hash collision probabilities of the outer hash function.

Comment: @Oli:  what if I concatenate the two hashes(losing some space in the process)?  Still doesn't help?

Comment: @Matt: Edited original question to make it more clear.

Comment: Considering SHA-x is designed to well-distribute "any" input .. I don't see what advantage the pre-hashes would result in. That is, **a change to a *single* bit in the SHA-x input will change the output significantly**. (If anything, I would imagine the pre-hashing would be *detrimental* if they could be exploited - on purpose or by accident - due to not being "as robust" as SHA-x or otherwise collaping the input space.)

Comment: `CONCAT(SHA(x),SHA(f(x))`, where `f` is some function that alters - but does not collapse - the input (e.g. reverse), will result in a larger output space, yes. Will this even matter? I don't know, but highly doubt it.

Comment: @pst: looking at the actually probabilities I am now convinced that the chance is so slim that it's silly to worry about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "reasonable" hash functions, then by concatenating, all you're doing is creating a hash function with a larger output space.  So yes, this reduces the probability of collision.

But either way, it's probably not worth worrying about.  2^320 is something like the number of particles in the universe.  So you only need to worry if you're expecting attackers.

Comment: what if I concatenated two distinct hashes on the same string?  Is it not true that the probability of two distinct hash f()s yielding the same value for a given string is less than the probability of only one of them doing the same?

Comment: @omnisis: Assuming they're reasonable independent hashes, yes, that's true.  But in your question, you're then passing this result into another hash function.

Comment: @omnisis: Hmm, you've now completely changed the question.  Obviously, a longer hash function is much less likely to see collisions than a shorter hash function (assuming they're both "reasonable").

Comment: Yeah sorry about that.  One more....Should I care about using a crypto like hashing function for at least one of the hashes or can I "get away" with a 2 functions that are smaller?

Comment: @omnisis: I don't know, but I doubt it matters!  Either way, the chance of a collision is 1 in 2^160, which is orders of magnitude greater than the number of particles in the universe...

Comment: If you post answer a new answer I'll give you credit...Again..sorry

Comment: IIRC the estimate on particles in the universe is 10^100 ~= 2^300.  But otherwise this is great.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the wrong question initially.  This was probably the question I was looking for:

[Probability of SHA1 collisions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867191/probability-of-sha1-collisions)

This was also illuminating

[Understanding sha-1 collision weakness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147830/understanding-sha-1-collision-weakness)

I guess it's fair to ask if I had two hash functions whose concatenated size was smaller than 20 bytes say 2 distinct 32-bit hashing functions.  If concatenating those produces a probability that is small enough to ignore in practice since 2 (or even 3) of those concatenated would be smaller than SHA-1.