# PHP - MD5, SHA, Hashing security

Tags: php, security, hash, md5, sha1

I'm the developer of a new website built in PHP and I'm wondering what exactly is the best
thing to use for hashing. I've looked at md5 and sha1 but is there anything more secure.
I'm sorry if this is a nooby question but I'm new to PHP Security and I'm trying to make my
site as secure as possible. Also what is a salt?
Thanks,
Waseem

Comment: What are you going to use the hash for? As for salt see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)

Comment: Passwords and Usernames

Comment: Hint: `bcrypt` - that is all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First off md5 and sha1 have been proven to be vunrable to collision attacks and can be rainbow
tabled easily (When they see if you hash is the same in their database of common passwords).
There are currently two things that are secure enough for passwords, that you can use.
The first being sha512. sha512 is a sub-version of SHA2. SHA2 has not yet been proven to be
vunrable to collision attacks and sha512 will generate a 512 bit hash. Here is an example of
how to use sha512:

```
<?php
hash('sha512',$password);
```

The other option is called bcrypt. bcrypt is famous for its secure hashes. Its
probably the most secure one out there and most customizable one too.
Before you want to start using bcrypt you need to check if your sever has it enabled, Enter 
this code:

```
<?php
if (defined("CRYPT_BLOWFISH") && CRYPT_BLOWFISH) {
    echo "CRYPT_BLOWFISH is enabled!";
}else {
echo "CRYPT_BLOWFISH is not available";
}
```

If it returns that it is enabled then the next step is easy, All you need to do to bcrypt a 
password is (Note for more customizability you need to see this [How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)):

```
crypt($password, $salt);
```

Now to answer your second question. A salt is usally a random string that you add at the end of
 all you passwords when you hash them. Using a salt means if some one gets your database 
they can not check the hashes for common passwords. Checking the database is called using a rainbow table. You should always use a salt when hashing!!

Here are my proofs for the SHA1 and MD5 collision attack vulnerabilities:
http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/10/when_will_we_se.html, http://eprint.iacr.org/2010/413.pdf, http://people.csail.mit.edu/yiqun/SHA1AttackProceedingVersion.pdf, http://conf.isi.qut.edu.au/auscert/proceedings/2006/gauravaram06collision.pdf and [Understanding sha-1 collision weakness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1147830/understanding-sha-1-collision-weakness)

Comment: Just for the record: bcrypt is famous for _not_ being fast but very slow (http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/).

Comment: @ckruse Sorry for the mistake I'll fix it :)

Comment: bcrypt is so last week, use scrypt ;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10149554/are-there-any-php-implementations-of-scrypt

Comment: Please cite your source for proven SHA1 collision attacks... because it's news to the whole crypto community. [Some reference material for you](http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2012/10/when_will_we_se.html)

Comment: Please do your homework: [collision attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_attack) are irrelevant in this case; [preimage attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preimage_attack) are [still infeasible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5#Preimage_vulnerability).

Comment: I would rather a slow secure method over something being fast and less-secure.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of the salt is to slow down an attacker from comparing a list of pre-generated hashes against the target hash.

Instead of needing to pre-compute one "hashed" value for each plaintext password, an attacker needs to precompute 16384 "hashed" values for each plaintext password (2^7 * 2^7).

That kinda pales today but was pretty big when the crypt function was first developed - the computational power to pre-compute that many passwords times the number of plaintext password you suspect (dictionary) was pretty high.

Not so much today which is why we have things like shadow passwords, other core password functions besides crypt and every sysad wanting you to pick a password that would not show up in a dictionary.

If the hashes you want to generate are for passwords this is a well accepted method of implementing it.

http://www.openwall.com/phpass/

Comment: I have no idea how you got the number 16384 and salting is as important as ever. When you combine each password with a different salt, then an attacker would have to build a rainbow-table for every single password, and cannot use 1 rainbow-table to get all passwords. That is the purpose of the salt, it is not a secret and it won't help against dictionary attacks.

Comment: @martinstoeckli - I think Danilo was assuming two 7-bit ASCII characters as salt, thus 16,384 possibilities.  And I think you guys are "talking past each other", i.e., I think you are both saying the same thing.  Instead of a rainbow table for "n" passwords, now it's 16K entries for each of the "n" passwords (or, conceptually, a 16K x "n" matrix now, instead of an "n" element array).

Comment: @Dan - Oh well, that sounds plausible. Then i can only add, that today a salt should contain about 128 bits, BCrypt expects 22 characters for example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to do this for passwords, then **do not use MD5 or SHA1**. They are known to be weak and insecure, even with salt.

If you're using them for other purposes (eg providing a hash of a file to confirm its authenticity, or a random hash database column to provide a pseudo-random sort order) then they are fine (up to a point), but not for passwords or anything else that you would consider needing to be kept secure.

The current best-practice algorithm for password hasing is BCrypt, with suitable salting.

And the best way to implement BCrypt password hashing in PHP is to use PHP's new password API. This API will be featured as a set of built-in functions in the next version of PHP, v5.5, due for release in the next few months. The good news is that they have also released a backward-compatibility version for users of current versions of PHP (5.3 and 5.4), so even though PHP 5.5 isn't released yet, you can start using the new API immediately.

You can download the compatibility library from here: https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Also: You asked what "salt" is. Since I've mentioned it a couple of times in this answer, I should address that part of the question too.

Salt is basically an additional string added to the password when hashing it, in order to make it harder to crack.

For example, an attacker may know in advance what the hashed value is for a given password string, or even a whole lot of given password strings. If he can get hold of your hashed data and you haven't used a salt, then he can just compare your hashes against his list of known passwords, and if any of your users are using an easy to guess password, they'll be cracked in seconds, regardless of what hashing method was used.

However, if you've added a secret extra string to the password when you hash it, then the hashed value won't match the standard hash for the original password, thus making it harder for the attacker to find the value.

The good news is that if you're using the API I mentioned above, then you don't need to worry too much about the details of this, as the API handles the salting for you.

Hope that helps.